# How to get user notified when he click on submit button in a jsp page?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I am developing a sample app using spring mvc 3.0. I have jsp page where user can add rows as many as user wants and user can enter the data in the rows. When click on submit button the enter data displayed in the next page. Now I want to send the user entered data to his mail id using java mail in spring mvc (gmail smtp server optional).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way with Spring's API consists of configuring a mail sender:

```
<bean id="mainMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="session" ref="session" />
</bean>
```

In your service you use the sender to create the message, fill it and send it:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mainMailSender")
private JavaMailSender sender;

public void sendMail(..){

    MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
    ..
    message.setSender(..);
    message.setSubject(..).
    ..

    sender.send(message);
}
```

Notice that ref="session" should reference a javax.mail.Session. Alternatively, you can use a properties (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html#setJavaMailProperties%28java.util.Properties%29) with the mail config info.

Or event set the config manually as in 24.3: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html